# Movie about a stopwatch that can actually stop time

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, tv

What is the movie or tv show about a man who has a stopwatch enables him to stop time..airplanes, people, etc? Eventually, he breaks the watch and cannot fix it?

Comment: Can we get some more details?  [There's sort of a few works that deal with stopping time, especially with watches.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeStandsStill)

Comment: I seem to remember seeing a movie of this nature i think it might have come out in the early 2000s

Comment: @SamIam [Clockstoppers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0157472/)?

Comment: @phantom42 I think so

Comment: @phantom42 I was thinking that too. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: But I'd bet money that @gnovice is right! The original question describes that episode exactly. I've never actually watched Clockstoppers - I'm just vaguely familiar and know that the timeframe fits what SamIAm remembered.

Comment: My first thought was bernards watch, but thats a child rather than a man: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0171980/

Comment: There's also a great episode from Friday the Thirteenth: The Series which features such a watch.

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like the [*Twilight Zone*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone_%281959_TV_series%29) episode ["A Kind of a Stopwatch"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Kind_of_a_Stopwatch).

> Patrick McNulty is a self-important bore in his 40s who has accomplished very little.

....

> McNulty goes to a bar, where he drives away the other patrons with his opinions about a sporting event. The bar owner requests that McNulty patronize another establishment. McNulty ignores him and buys a drink for the sole remaining patron, a drunk. The drunk gives McNulty his stopwatch. Thinking it an odd gift, McNulty quickly discovers that it can stop the passage of time.

....

> McNulty attempts to rob a bank, but he drops the watch. It breaks, freezing time permanently. Unaware of a way to repair it, McNulty runs around in a panic, ultimately begging the frozen people to talk or move, vainly promising to change his ways if only they will recognize him.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the made for TV movie "*The Girl, The Gold Watch, and Everything*" starring Robert Hays and Pam Dawber (of *Mork & Mindy* fame).

IMDB profile is here:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080792/?ref_=sr_1

Comment: That was my first thought, too, but that would require at least one wrong detail.. In TGTGWAE, he never breaks the watch.

Comment: I wasn't sure how the movie ended, it's been so long. From the wikipedia plot description, I think it is the Twilight Zone episode referenced by gnovice.

Answer (score 3):

My first inclination was for [Clockstoppers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0157472/).

Though the watch doesn't actually stop time, rather it speeds up the users molecules giving the impression that everything else is stopped.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few movies and TV shows that featured a pocket watch that could stop time as well as one movie featuring a digital wrist watch. They all appeared to have been based on John D. MacDonald's 1962 sci-fi novel 'The Girl, the Gold Watch and Everything.' John D MacDonald may have been influenced by Murray Leinster's short story 'The Eternal Now' from 1944. And Murray Leinster may have been influenced by a short story by H. G. Wells, 'The New Accelerator' in 1901.

Here's a list of movies and TV shows that feature a watch that can stop time. I'm sure this list is not complete as there are probably stuff out there that I am not aware of.

Twilight Zone episode A Kind of a Stopwatch 1963

The Girl, the Gold Watch, and Everything 1980 (TV movie adaptation of John D. MacDonald's 1962 novel)

Friday the 13th The Series episode 13 O'clock 1988

Bernard's Watch 1997-2005 (British TV show)

Clock Stoppers 2002 (the one with the digital wrist watch)

Answer (score 1):

Could you be thinking of "[Greatest American Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Greatest_American_Hero)". It was a TV sitcom from the '80's rather than a film, but there were several feature-length episodes.

Everthing turned red when he clicked the stopwatch and they played a ticktock sound and everyone froze in time except him.